# Multiple Errors in class object with Turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Currently working on a class that keeps track of score in a snake game (using the turtle module) but for some reason I get
multiple unexpected errors here is my code and errors

code:

```
from turtle import Turtle as T


class Score(T):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        self.color('white')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x=0, y=270)
        self.write = (f'The score is: {self.score}', align='center', font=('Ariel', 24, 'Normal'))
        self.hideturtle()

    def increase_score(self):
        self.score += 1
        self.write = f'The score is: {self.score}'
```

errors I get

```
unresolved reference 'self': 11
unresolved reference 'align': 11
unexpected expression syntax: 11
end of statement expected: 11
Statement expected, found py:RPAR
```

Comment: Did you mean to call the `Turtle.write` method? If so it should be `self.write(f'The score is: {self.score}', align='center', font=('Ariel', 24, 'Normal'))` and also `self.write = f'The score is: {self.score}'` should be changed to `self.write(f'The score is: {self.score}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`turtle.write()` - This function is used to write text at the current turtle position.

Syntax :
`turtle.write(arg, move=False, align=’left’, font=(‘Arial’, 8, ‘normal’))`

Remove the `=` sign so you can actually call that function